# How does mysqldump write binary data into files for MySQL logical backup?

Tags: mysql, c, character-encoding

I am using mysqldump to back up a table. The schema is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATA` varbinary(64) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I can use the following command to backup my data in the table.

**mysqldump -uroot -p123456 tdb > dump.sql**.

Now I want to write my own code using the MySQL c interface to generate the file similar to dump.sql.
So I just

- read the data, and store it int char* p(using function mysql_fetch_row);
- write data into file using fprintf(f,"%s",p);

However, when I check the table fields written into the file, I find that the file generated by mysqldump and by my own program are different.For example,

- one data field in the file generated by mysqldump

  `` '[[     \\^X\í^G\ÑX`    C;·Qù^Dô7<8a>¼!{<96>aÓ¹<8c>     HÀaHr^Q^^½n÷^Kþ<98>IZ<9f>3þ' ``
- one data field in the file generated by my program

  `` [[      \^Xí^GÑX`       C;·Qù^Dô7<8a>¼!{<96>aÓ¹<8c>     HÀaHr^Q^^½n÷^Kþ<98>IZ<9f>3þ ``

So, My question is: Why is writting data using sprintf(f,"%s",xx) for backup not correct? Is it enough to just add ' ' in the front and end of the string? If so, what if the data of that field happen to have ' in it?

Also, I wonder what it means to write some unprintable characters into a text file.

---

Also, I read [stackoverflow.com/questions/16559086](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559086/does-mysqldump-handle-binary-data-reliably) and tried **--hex-blob** option. Is it OK if I transform every byte of the binary data into hex form and then write simple text strings into the dump.sql.

Then, instead of getting

`` '[[     \\^X\í^G\ÑX`    C;·Qù^Dô7<8a>¼!{<96>aÓ¹<8c>     HÀaHr^Q^^½n÷^Kþ<98>IZ<9f>3þ' ``

I got something like

`0x5B5B095C18ED07D1586009433BB751F95E44F4378ABC217B9661D3B98C0948C0614872111EBD6EF70BFE98495A9F33FE`

All the characters are printable now!

However, If I choose this method, I wonder if I can meet problems when I use other encoding schemes other than latin1.

Also, the above words are all my own ideas, I also wonder I there are other ways to back up data using the C interface.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: --hex-blob has saved me a massive headache. really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

`latin1`, `utf8`, etc are `CHARACTER SETs`.  They apply to `TEXT` and `VARCHAR` columns, *not* `BLOB` and `VARBINARY` columns.

Using `--hex-blob` is a good idea.

If you have "unprintable characters" in `TEXT` or `CHAR`, then either you have been trying to put a BLOB into such -- naughty -- or the print mechanism does is not set for the appropriate charset.