# How to export database from PhpMyAdmin with emojis?

Tags: php, utf-8, phpmyadmin, emoji

Usual problem, when exporting - importing a database, the emojis goes ??? ... I cant use "`mysqldump`" or any command line based command for it, all I have is `phpmyadmin`. I can see "exporting charset" but it can only be UTF-8, not `utf8mb4`. Then what to do? Of course, I can write the whole exporting function in php, if no other choice... but how?

Comment: You'll need to keep the encoding, plus use a font that has the proper glyph... just like UTF-8 characters get garbled when viewed in a 1-byte encoding

Comment: Does the exported file include correct emoji characters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does mysqldump handle binary data reliably?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559086/does-mysqldump-handle-binary-data-reliably)